# HTML Body with HTML Attachment

Tags: html, email

I have been trying to build a RAG Status based milestone tracker which will give the status of loading (as a RAG) in the mail body (has to be HTML) and as an attachment I have to give the actual volume of the data.

I have prepared both body and the attachment.

The point I am struggling in is to have both of them sent via a single mail.

I have gone through a number of articles which have suggested using mutt,sendmail,mailx,mail,etc. . but none seem to work out for me as either I am getting the HTML body or HTML attachment but not both.

Can somebody please help ?

Body : a.html
Attachment : b.html

Requirement to send the report (body+ attachment) via a single mail.
Platform : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.10 (Tikanga)
Mail receiver : Microsoft Outlook